# Various ITMS errors when trying to submit archive to App Store

Tags: ios, xcode, submission

So this is a weird one — I get the following errors when trying to submit my archive to the App Store:

```
ERROR ITMS-90049: "This bundle is invalid. The bundle identifier contains disallowed characters. [See the section of the Application Programming Guide entitled The APplication Bundle.]"

ERROR ITMS-90049 "This bundle is invalid. The bundle identifier contains disallowed characters

ERROR ITMS-90056: "This bundle is invalid. The Info.plist file is missing the required key: CFBundleVersion."
```

From my plist:

```
<key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
<string>com.myApp.app</string>
```

…

```
<key>CFBundleVersion</key>
<string>3.1.5</string>
```

…

```
<key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
<string>3.1.4</string>
```

Running xCode 7.0.1

Comment: Hi... I have the same issues. But I am trying change account and create a new certificates but doesn't work. If you have another idea please share. Thanks

Comment: try to delete the third-party SDK's plist file. It does work to my project.

Comment: delete info.plist in 3th lib

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Update XCode to 7.1, it is posted yesterday.

Use the newest XCode to submit will be OK.

==================================================

As muyexi said, I delete TencentOpen SDK info.plist,then submit success.

[image: delete TencentOpen SDK's info.plist]

Comment: I am using the new Xcode 7.1 (7B91b), but the issue is still there and I don't have any 3Ps Info.plist files. The issue might be on Apple side, I guess.

Comment: @FabrizioProsperi you need to check every SDKs in the project . in my case, it's cocoapod has info.plist.

Answer (score 5):

Check if the third-party's has plist file.Apple may mixed the third-party Sdk plist with the local plist file. Delete the third-party's plist file then upload success.

Comment: I removed one of the 3rd party .plist's from my project and it resolved the issue

Answer (score 4):

I solve this by following this [link](http://blog.csdn.net/h1101723183/article/details/49339681), add `Bundle identifier` which is missing in info.plist of [TencentOpen SDK](http://wiki.open.qq.com/wiki/mobile/SDK%E4%B8%8B%E8%BD%BD).

Comment: Deleting TencentOpen SDK's info.plist solved the problem for me, without upgrading Xcode to 7.1.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using cocoapods, make sure you do a

```
pod update
```

That will update all your pod files and solved this issue for me!

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to expand an answer given by @silvon and link more keywords to this question.

Apparently, iTunes Connect backend now validates every single bundle shipped with your app. If a bundle contains Info.plist file, it *must have* `CFBundleVersion` and `CFBundleShortVersionString` keys.

So, if you are using any 3rd party frameworks (specifically, with Cocoapods), make sure that `Info.plist` in each framework bundle (if exists) contain these keys.

Answer (score 1):

For all of you using CocoaPods, simply try to

```
pod update
```

In my case, it was a third party library loaded via cocoapods, but the update did the trick. BTW, none of the libraries had new versions, the update seems to repair some bad things too.

Comment: I did as you suggested, with the same result: no pods were updated, but the next time I archived, I was able to upload successfully.

Answer (score 0):

iTunes Connect is currently experiencing major issues. I can't post any citations as I'm unaware of an iTunes Connect support status page, but I spent a while on the phone with them earlier today for a similar issue.

Comment: I use bitrise.io and iTunes connect api intergration. I have the same issue

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be some Issues from Apples's Side, I am experiencing the same issues, I would suggest to wait for some time before making any major changes.

This seems to be happening a lot lately, after some time, It starts working again .

Answer (score 0):

I did the same step as Silvon mention. 
Removed all third party lib's info.plist (pods as well) with xcode 6.4. Works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the answer with top rate , but you need to check every SDKs in the project . in my case, it's cocoapod has info.plist. I deleted it and everything works. Xcode 7.1 still has this problem.