# This bundle is invalid. The Info.plist file is missing the required key: CFBundleVersion

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I keep getting an error when submitting a build using Xcode 7.0.1 and Xcode 7.1 even on an archive that was accepted by apple a day ago.

`ERROR ITMS-90056: "This bundle is invalid. The Info.plist file is missing the required key: CFBundleVersion."`

Comment: Check the info.plist file to see if the value for this key is actually missing and either add it or file a bug report with Apple

Comment: [This thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33271789/various-itms-errors-when-trying-to-submit-archive-to-app-store) may help you sort this out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check all the frameworks in your app. It's possible one has an empty value for CFBundleVersion. (Facebook Pop is currently guilty of this.)