# Crash in the execution of a queue glmtl.telemetry

Tags: objective-c, crash, ios14, xcode12

Exactly 60 seconds after launching my app it crashes with an uncaught exception:

```
libc++abi.dynlib: terminating app due to uncaught exception of type NSException 
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception of type 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSDictionaryM setObject:forKey:]: object cannot be nil (key: BundleVersion)'
```

The crashing thread has a random number (it is #7 in the attached screenshot) and it is always created for an unknown to me queue `glmtl.telemetry`.

The crash occurs only on one device (iPhone 11 Pro Max) and iOS 14.0 (it was then replicated with iOS 14.0.1).

I am not using in the project anywhere a key "BundleVersion". (There is CFBundleVersion in the info.plist, but does not seem to be related).

Can this be caused by the project sources?

[image]

Comment: I've had the same error. I thought it went away, but then it returned.

Comment: Did you ever fix this?

Comment: @dk123 Kind of... Healing the git status (fixing all [?] in Xcode's navigator) of all files and directories in the project magically resolved the problem. I never found the relationship.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an explanation of the issue but the crash stopped appearing after adding a group of missing resource files to a folder (not a group but a folder) in the bundle.

Answer (score 1):

### Fix

I am having the same issue. In my case, I needed to add [`CFBundleVersion`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/cfbundleversion) to the project's `Info.plist` since the exception mentions the `"BundleVersion"` key and because I recalled seeing [XCode complain about invalid bundles when that key is missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33271789/various-itms-errors-when-trying-to-submit-archive-to-app-store).

My guess is that those [recommended `CFBundle*` keys](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html) should be set for the main project's `Info.plist` and any embedded framework or projects with their own `Info.plist`. I'm just surprised XCode 12 doesn't raise that error right now at build time.

### Source of the issue (?)

Do you use `OpenGL` in your app? I could not find what `glmtl` is, but it seems that the crash occurs exactly 1 minute after I instantiate a new `OpenGL` context. The crash will still occur after 1 minute if I delete the context before that, but it will be delayed another minute if I create a new instance in between.

Comment: Yes, I use OpenGL. The queue's name ```gltml``` suggest some relationship to ```OpenGL / Metal```. The crash stopped occurring after fixing a git issue - one folder with assets had a question mark in the project navigator ```[?]```. Seems completely unrelated, but it helped.

Comment: In my project `CFBundleVersion` was set to `$(CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION)`. After I rewrote this value to the actual number (for example "3"), the crashes stopped. But every time when you set bundle version in Project tab, it will rewrite the value in info.plist back to `$(CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION)`, which again trigger the crash :(((

Comment: @mike-keskinov yes that's annoying... Apple/XCode seem to want to enforce `CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION` as the value of `CFBundleVersion`, though you can always revert the change and it will still work with a hardcoded value... However, it should still work as long `CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION` is set (which should be under "TARGETS > YourApp > General > Identity > Build").

Do you see `CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION` equal to anything if you inspect your `project.pbxproj` file?